# Python decorator for debouncing including function arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, debouncing

How could one write a debounce decorator in python which debounces not only on function called but also on the function arguments/combination of function arguments used?

Debouncing means to supress the call to a function within a given timeframe, say you call a function 100 times within 1 second but you only want to allow the function to run once every 10 seconds a debounce decorated function would run the function  once 10 seconds after the last function call if no new function calls were made. Here I'm asking how one could debounce a function call with specific function arguments.

An example could be to debounce an expensive update of a person object like:

```
@debounce(seconds=10)
def update_person(person_id):
    # time consuming, expensive op
    print('>>Updated person {}'.format(person_id))
```

Then debouncing on the function - including function arguments:

```
update_person(person_id=144)
update_person(person_id=144)
update_person(person_id=144)
>>Updated person 144

update_person(person_id=144)
update_person(person_id=355)
>>Updated person 144
>>Updated person 355
```

So calling the function update_person with the same person_id would be supressed (debounced) until the 10 seconds debounce interval has passed without a new call to the function with that same person_id.

There's a few debounce decorators but none includes the function arguments, example: https://gist.github.com/walkermatt/2871026

I've done a similar throttle decorator by function and arguments:

```
def throttle(s, keep=60):

    def decorate(f):

        caller = {}

        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            nonlocal caller

            called_args = '{}'.format(*args)
            t_ = time.time()

            if caller.get(called_args, None) is None or t_ - caller.get(called_args, 0) >= s:
                result = f(*args, **kwargs)

                caller = {key: val for key, val in caller.items() if t_ - val > keep}
                caller[called_args] = t_
                return result

            # Keep only calls > keep
            caller = {key: val for key, val in caller.items() if t_ - val > keep}
            caller[called_args] = t_

        return wrapped

    return decorate
```

The main takaway is that it keeps the function arguments in caller[called_args]

See also the difference between throttle and debounce: http://demo.nimius.net/debounce_throttle/

**Update:**

After some tinkering with the above throttle decorator and the threading.Timer example in the gist, I actually think this should work:

```
from threading import Timer
from inspect import signature
import time


def debounce(wait):
    def decorator(fn):
        sig = signature(fn)
        caller = {}

        def debounced(*args, **kwargs):
            nonlocal caller

            try:
                bound_args = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
                bound_args.apply_defaults()
                called_args = fn.__name__ + str(dict(bound_args.arguments))
            except:
                called_args = ''

            t_ = time.time()

            def call_it(key):
                try:
                    # always remove on call
                    caller.pop(key)
                except:
                    pass

                fn(*args, **kwargs)

            try:
                # Always try to cancel timer
                caller[called_args].cancel()
            except:
                pass

            caller[called_args] = Timer(wait, call_it, [called_args])
            caller[called_args].start()

        return debounced

    return decorator
```

Comment: Define "debouncing" in this context; expected input and output? Also, your input and output is dependent on time, so you might want to provide that.

Comment: Very mildly relevant: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html

Comment: You might want to explain what "debounce" means for those not familiar with keyboard hardware implementation details

Comment: What have you tried so far to implement the debounce decorator? You have demonstrated that you know how to write a decorator, and the debounce algorithm is not particularly complicated. The linked gist does show a debounce decorator with arguments. What specific issue do you need help with?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi as I have clarified in the question, it's debouncing on the called functions and its arguments - not the decorator's arguments. The first gist linked above uses threading.Timer to debounce the function call - but how could that be implemented to account for the arguments used in the function call, like the throttle decorator in the question which holds the arguments in caller[called_args]

Comment: You could use functools lru_cache implementation or customise it further like how cachetools does, which also has an option to timeout. https://cachetools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Thanks @mkrieger1, updated the example

Comment: I still have very little clue what debouce means here, but I do see something odd in your code that I do understand: The `'{}'.format(*args)` expression almost certainly doesn't do what you want it to do. It's equivalent to `str(args[0])`, I think. If you fall sophisticated argument handling, you probably want to use `inspect.Signature`, it would be very tedious to reinvent it.

Comment: @Blckknght, thank you so much - that's exactly what's needed to get a safe key for any configuration of arguments! Updated the code

Comment: @Blckknght; throttle - let first call through supress following, debounce - supress all except the last call. Both throttle and debounce is within a given interval in time.

Comment: That's a nice example on how to implement debouncing in Python. I'm coming from Node.js, so it was a perfect start for my debouncing algorithm in Python, although I didn't implement it as a decorator, just integrated it straight to my code.

Comment: If you found a solution you should post it as an answer, not in the question.,

Answer (score 6):

I've had the same need to build a debounce annotation for a personal project, after stumbling upon [the same gist / discussion](https://gist.github.com/walkermatt/2871026) you have, I ended up with the following solution:

```
import threading
def debounce(wait_time):
    """
    Decorator that will debounce a function so that it is called after wait_time seconds
    If it is called multiple times, will wait for the last call to be debounced and run only this one.
    """

    def decorator(function):
        def debounced(*args, **kwargs):
            def call_function():
                debounced._timer = None
                return function(*args, **kwargs)
            # if we already have a call to the function currently waiting to be executed, reset the timer
            if debounced._timer is not None:
                debounced._timer.cancel()

            # after wait_time, call the function provided to the decorator with its arguments
            debounced._timer = threading.Timer(wait_time, call_function)
            debounced._timer.start()

        debounced._timer = None
        return debounced

    return decorator
```

I've created an open-source project to provide functions such as debounce, throttle, filter ... as decorators, contributions are more than welcome to improve on the solution I have for these decorators / add other useful decorators: [decorator-operations repository](https://github.com/salesforce/decorator-operations/blob/master/decoratorOperations/debounce_functions/debounce.py#L6)

Comment: This does not seem to work when there are multiple different calls with unique arguments and you want it to debounce them individually. Only the last one is getting through in Python 3.9 when I am testing.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my 2 cents for simplicity:

- Proper wrapping
- Empty lambda for initialization
- No ifs, no try/except(s)

Check code:

```
import functools
from threading import Timer

def debounce(timeout: float):
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            wrapper.func.cancel()
            wrapper.func = Timer(timeout, func, args, kwargs)
            wrapper.func.start()
        
        wrapper.func = Timer(timeout, lambda: None)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```